# Push notification doesn't appear on notification center or locked screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I'm working on an iOS app that uses push notifications. I followed this [raywenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1).
I receive the notification when the app is running and it call the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method.

But the notification doesn't appear on the notification center or on looked screen neither if the app is running nor it is terminated.

***This is the payload object***

```
payload =
{ 
   alert = "Title goes here";
   myid = 304;
   xxxxxx = 51;
   sound = default;
};
```

Comment: What is the body of the notification?

Comment: it can be because your app is not configured to show this way. Check in 'Notifications' options from 'Settings' app

Comment: @azimov It is enabled from settings

Comment: @AhdRadwan can you show a notification payload example ?

Comment: @azimov I have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alert and sound must be in an `aps` object within your payload:

```
{
   "aps":
   {
     "alert": "blah",
     "sound": "default",
   },
   "myid": 12345
}
```